# How to show the total value of multiple text field?

Tags: javascript, html

how can I show the total value of all id="total" in id="grand". This is my whole code. Only HTML and Javascript should be used. I don't know how to add the value of each. the javascript is exeuted when the user checked the checkbox. the value of the checkbox will be multiplied to the value of the dropdown value. then the product will be displayed in the input id="total". I want sum all the value in the input id=total and display it in the input id="grand"

```
<p><center><font size="5">Total Amount: <input type="text" id="grand" name="grand" value="P0.00"></input></p>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td colspan=3><h2>Specialty Cakes</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><center><img src=special\blackforest_small.jpg ><br>Black Forest</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" value="550.00"onclick="special1()">Buy P550.00</input><br><input type="text" id="total1" name="total1" value="P0.00"size="8"></input><br>
QTY: <select id="qty1" name="qty1" onchange="special1()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><center><img src=special\chocolata_small.jpg><br>Chocolata</center></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check2" value="550.00"onclick="special2()">Buy P500.00</input><br><input type="text" id="total2" name="total2" value="P0.00"size="8"></input><br>
QTY: <select id="qty2" name="qty2" onchange="special2()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
function special1(){
var m = document.getElementById("check1").checked;
var x = document.getElementById("check1").value;
var y = document.getElementById("qty1").value;
var z = 0;
if (m == true){
z = "P" + x * y;
}
document.getElementById("total1").value = z;
}
function special2(){
var m = document.getElementById("check2").checked;
var x = document.getElementById("check2").value;
var y = document.getElementById("qty2").value;
var z = 0;
if (m == true){
z = "P" + x * y;
}
document.getElementById("total2").value = z;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS + works from left to right. But adding string to enything else will produce another string, so you need to watch for order of your operations.

```
z = "P" + (x * y);
```

Comment: i edited the main problem to be understood well. please take a look

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parentheses to your calculations:

```
z = "P" + ( x * y );
          ^       ^
```

In this case your function will work as expected. What you have now is concatenations.

And seems like you need to convert that numbers to floats, using [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function. And remove first char if it is always starts with `P` using [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) method

So final result should be:

```
z = "P" + ( parseFloat( x.substr( 1 ) ) * parseFloat( y.substr( 1 ) ) ).toFixed( 2 );
```

[`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) will format your float number to have always 2 numbers after dot.

Comment: i edited the main problem to be understood well. please take a look